# MATLAB - avoiding loops to create a matrix based on the elements of other vectors

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have vectors `x,y,z`, of lengths `n,m,l`. I want to create a cell matrix `Q` using the elements of those vectors. Naively one could use a for loop as so:

```
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        for k = 1:l
            Q{i,j,k} = someFunction(x(i), y(j), z(k));
        end
     end
end
```

Each element of `Q` is a vector.

Is there a more elegant (and probably less slow) way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x=[1 2 3 4];
y=[5 6];
z=[7 8 9];
[X Y Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
someFunc = @(a,b,c)[a b c]; #% test function; use whatever you want
Q = arrayfun(someFunc,X,Y,Z,'UniformOutput',false);
Q{1,1,1} #% output: [1 5 7]
```

If someFunction is defined elsewhere, use `arrayfun(@someFunction,X,Y,Z);` to get a handle to it.  (`arrayfun` uses each element of the arguments as args to the function handle you provide - it, and the related cellfun, are key in avoiding loops.)

Comment: +1 - you beat me to exactly this method, using meshgrid then arrayfun :)

Comment: Nice. Suppose I had a matrix `M` and `someFunc` operated on the columns of `M`. Can `arrayfun` deal with this as well?

Comment: In that case, my approach would be to use `num2cell(M,dim)` - dim being 1 to turn each columns  into a cell - and use the result with `cellfun`

Comment: @tmpearce - would X,Y,Z need to be cells as well?

Comment: I'm having a hard time fully understanding your hypothetical code here, but what I can say is that all the args to cellfun need to be cell arrays of the same size.

Answer (score 1):

With `someFunction` is designed this way, then it does not look possible.

You should change `someFunction` to take matrices and return a matrix. Then the problem becomes writing the specific `someFunction` using matrix operations. Altough a generic solution to the original problem seems not possible, when you consider a specific function (like I suggested here) it can be possible.