# loop through element of meshgrid matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to loop through a meshgrid to create a matrix of vectors. If I have:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:2,1:2)
```

can someone explain looping through each element to get a matrix which equals:

```
matrix =
 [x(1,1) y(1,1)] [x(1,2) y(1,2)]
 [x(2,1) y(2,1)] [x(2,2) y(2,2)]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: difficult when i'm a beginner at matlab!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `2x4` matrix with the values of `x` and `y` interleaved, this will work:

```
matrix = zeros(2,4);
matrix(:,[1 3]) = x;
matrix(:,[2 4]) = y;
```

If instead you want a `2x2x2` matrix with `x` and `y` stacked, use `cat`:

```
matrix = cat(3,x,y);
```

This concatenates `x` and `y` along the third dimension.

Comment: this looks great, how would i do a nxn matrix. currently mine is 74x74, but there will be others ones depending on the dimensions of the image i read in.....

Comment: In the case of 74x74, what are the final dimensions you're hoping for?

Comment: Please check this answer, [very concise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743671/matlab-avoiding-loops-to-create-a-matrix-based-on-the-elements-of-other-vector?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could arrange each pair of coordinates as one row:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:2,1:2)
xy = [x(:) y(:)];
```

Thus:

```
>> xy =
     1     1           %# xy(1,:) = [x(1,1),y(1,1)]
     1     2           %# xy(2,:) = [x(2,1),y(2,1)]
     2     1           %# xy(3,:) = [x(1,2),y(1,2)]
     2     2           %# xy(4,:) = [x(2,2),y(2,2)]
```